# Why are there so many Scala collection view types?

Tags: scala, collections, lazy-evaluation

I am new to Scala, so I am trying to understand why calls on views return instances of `IndexedSeqViewS` and similar classes. Why does there need to be a different class for each operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because each view transformer operation (i.e. one that produces a new view, like `map`, `filter` or `slice`) creates a view that traverses the underlying collection in a different way.
Note that `IndexedSeqViewS` is not the actual name of that collection class - it is the prettified name that the `toString` returns.

For example, the `Mapped` view creates a view of the underlying collection such that each element of the underlying collection is transformed in some way.

This requires redefining the `foreach` as follows:

```
  trait Mapped[B] extends Transformed[B] {
    // ...
    def foreach[U](f: B => U) {
      for (x <- self)
        f(mapping(x))
    }
    // ...
  }
```

The `Filtered` view requires ignoring some elements while traversing:

```
  trait Filtered extends Transformed[A] {
    // ...
    def foreach[U](f: A => U) {
      for (x <- self)
        if (pred(x)) f(x)
    }
    // ...
  }
```

Since the collections have an inheritance-based design, to override the definition of `foreach` (and other methods like `apply`, `size`, etc.), a subclass needs to be introduced. In some alternative design, e.g. one based on typeclasses, a separate typeclass might have to be introduced to redefine what the `foreach` for a specific type.

Comment: Is there a separate class for each `Stream[T]` operation?

Comment: No, there are only 2 classes for each `Stream` operation -- empty stream and stream cons. However, these operations always return a `Stream` -- and every stream is traversed with the same `foreach` implementation. The `*View` operations are collection-independent -- the traversal of the underlying collection (`foreach`) in the view chain changes depending on what the previously called operation was -- and the other accessor operations (like `reduce`, `foreach` or `copyToArray`) are implemented in terms of `foreach`.

Comment: You could avoid the one-class-for-operation pattern if you were to include all the information about all the possible view transformations -- i.e. express all the view transformations in terms of one big `flatMapFilterGroupBySlice` method that embodies all the possible transformation information.